# How to start gazebo_ros gazebo with DART Physics engine?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to spawn a manipulator with urdf in gazebo and control using ros_control. How do I set the physics engine to be dart? I can get gazebo to run on its own by running: gazebo -e dart. How would I do the same with rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225131/how-to-start-gazebo_ros-gazebo-with-dart-physics-engine?/) by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2016-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. You can try adding the verbose flag, in case something isn't right the error or warning is displayed in console:

```
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo --verbose -e dart
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2016-01-26**:
Thanks, but I get this error: ROS get_physics_properties service call does not yet support physics engine [dart].

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2016-02-02**:
Am I missing something or is its a work in progress? If its a work in progress I could try to fix this and push the fix.

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2016-02-02**:
It works! Thanks.

**Comment by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) on 2017-11-26**:
I am facing the same problem. The terminal shows the error " ROS get_physics_properties service call does not yet support physics engine [dart].", however, the GUI is showing DART correctly. Is this a bug?

**Comment by [JohnBT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31607/johnbt/) on 2018-05-11**:
[same question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17028/does-gazebo_ros-launch-support-bullet/)